# EVE-NG doesn't run any nodes other than VPC and vIOS devices

Tags: networking, virtual, vmware, lab, cpu

I'm running a Community edition of EVE-NG on a nested virtualization setup but cannot run any of the "real" images in the lab. It's just the virtual PCs and Cisco vIOS devices that seem to run.

Images that have not run so far:

- Juniper
- ESXi
- Cisco Nexus

Setup details:

- CPU - i5 4 core RAM
- 12 GB  HDD
- 60 GB allocated to VM and just 23%
  full

According to the CPU/RAM calculator, the requirements seem fine but I'm wondering if the CPU is the culprit here.

Would anyone happen to know what is the recommended/minimum CPU specification for EVE-NG to run?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.eve-ng.net/index.php/documentation/installation/system-requirement/? However, products without optional, paid vendor support and host configurations/issues are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the valid topics. I'll be taking a note of that. About the installation page, my setup send to comply with the mentioned requirements.